# node.js passing parameter via querystring

Tags: node.js, hash, parameters, express

In a node.js application on the client side I have the following code in the button click event to call the node.js/express method "getProjectDetails" but because of the hash (#) character, Express is giving an error like "Unexpend end of input". So the question is how to escape the hash (#) character in the parameter query string that is passed to the node.js call?

```
// CLIENT SIDE CALLING CODE IN THE CLICK EVENT OF A BUTTON 
window.location.href = rootURL + 'getProjectDetails?project=ABCD#EFGH BLAH BLAH';
```

Whereas the below works fine:

```
window.location.href = rootURL + 'getProjectDetails?project=ABCDEFGH BLAH BLAH';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the hash by using %23 for #.

Comment: I am willing to do this manually but would like to understand why the JSON.stringify is not encoding it because my actual param is got via paramString = JSON.stringify(paramJSON) and then I append it to the node.js call.

Comment: Thanks Parker, your suggestion fixed it. var param = "ABCD#EFGH BLAH BLAH"; var paramNew = param.replace("#", "%23"); window.location.href = rootURL + 'getProjectDetails?project=' + paramNew;